# How to retrieve HTML content from server using $http in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I have a requirement like I need to fetch HTML body content using `$http` service in AngularJS.

When I am trying to get that I am getting entire HTML as a response, but I need only the body part of that content.

Comment: Why are you fetching HTML on the client side?

Comment: I am loading external content in my page and they are sending html only !!!

Answer (score 0):

You could find body inside the returned html.
But the best is definitely to update whatever service you call with `$http` so that it returns you only what you need (body).

```
angular.element(response).find('body')
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Can you write a bit more about why this is an appropriate way to get what the OP wants?